# How to reference a JSON List using an API

Tags: java, api, openweathermap

I would to refer to the pressure field in the List using the getPressure function

```
{
    "cod": "200",
    "message": 0,
    "cnt": 40,
    "list": [
        {
            "dt": 1612558800,
            "main": {
                "temp": -3.29,
                "feels_like": -6.55,
                "temp_min": -3.29,
                "temp_max": -3.16,
                "pressure": 1021,




 public String getPressure() {
            JsonArray weatherArray = obj.getJsonArray("main");
            JsonObject weatherObject = weatherArray.getJsonObject(0);
            return weatherObject.getString("pressure");
        }
```

How to write correctly getPressure functions to get the pressure value from the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    public String getPressure() {
       JsonArray weatherArray = obj.getJsonArray("list"); // list: []
       JsonObject weatherObject = weatherArray.getJsonObject(0); // first element of list
       JsonObject mainObject = weatherObject.getJsonObject("main"); // get main object
       return mainObject.getString("pressure"); // get Pressure of Main Object
    }
```

Comment: i changed getString to getInt and this works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### Suggestions

1. If you are planning to use this in a long term project, then consider defining the corresponding beans(mapping to json structure)
2. Use Jackson (ObjectMapper) or Gson to serialize/deserialize to/from json

### Current solution

```java
        JsonObject input  = new Gson().fromJson(json, JsonObject.class);
        System.out.println(input.getAsJsonArray("list").get(0)
            .getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("main").get("pressure").getAsInt());
```